# How i can detect the presense of sql code in a python file?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, hive, impala, nsregularexpression

I need to define a rule where an user cannot use sql code inside a .py file, they must to invoque all queries from a .sql file. Is there any method or library to detect sql statements in a .py file?
The users use Hive and Impala

Comment: Would it work if you just seached for the word SELECT?

Comment: Hi, i need search all the possible statements (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER, DROP...). It could work if i use regular expressions, but, maybe there is a unknown library for me.